# Run specs2 in sbt console

Tags: scala, specs2

Is it possible to run and try out specs2 in an sbt console? I tried === but that did not work because I assume it is a method in Specification class. I also tried:

```
class A extends Specification{ "b" should{ "do" in{ 3 === 4 } } }; (new A).toResult(true)
```

I'm suspecting the above should work if I know the right method to call, `values`?

Ideally I'd like it if I can execute single statements but if that is not possible, is there a way to run blocks of this sort?

PS: Is there a non-Fluent interface to specs2?

Comment: what do you call a "non-fluent" interface?

Comment: @Eric Thanks for the answer. By non-fluent, I mean that I'd like to say `collection.hasSize(3)` instead of `collection must have size(3)` , only a minor nit of my own so that I can infer types more easily. Thanks for the great framework btw.

Comment: You can "apply" any matcher: `be_==(1)(2).toResult`. Unfortunately for collections the type inference might not be better, depending on the matcher: `haveSize[List[Int]](3).apply(List(1,2,3)).toResult` (you need to annotate) and `contain(1)(List(1, 2)).toResult` (you don't). Also, it reads weird...

Comment: Otherwise you can define your own extended matcher methods if you don't want to use `must` but you have to do that for each matcher: `implicit class traversableMatchers[I](c: Traversable[I]) { def hasSize(n: Int) = haveSize[Traversable[I]](n).apply(c) }`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do the following to run expectations in the console:

```
import org.specs2._, matcher.MustMatchers._, execute._

def t[R:AsResult](r: =>R) = specs2.run(new Specification { def is = p^s2"test $r" })

// then
t(1 === 2)

[info] Specification
[info]
[error] x test
[error]  '1' is not equal to '2' (file:1)
[info]
[info] Total for specification Specification
[info] Finished in 5 ms
       1 example, 1 failure, 0 error
[info]
```